# getElementById from a @Html.DisplayFor checkbox in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Having worked long and hard on this I am stumped.

From this html

```
<td><span class="sessioncheckbox">  
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S15)</span> </td>
```

I am trying to extract out the contents of the checkbox from the generated DisplayFor

```
<input disabled="disabled" class="check-box" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

with the following Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".sessioncheckbox").each(function () {
                if (document.getElementById(".sessioncheckbox").innerHTML) {
                    $(".sessioncheckbox").addClass("badge badge-default trigger");
                };
            });
        });
```

But this line doesn't work

```
if (document.getElementById(".sessioncheckbox").innerHTML)
```

How do I get it if the **checkbox = checked**?

Cheers

Comment: getElementById search for elements by Id but you are searching for .sessioncheckbox which is a className. You can try a different selector like ```document.getElementsByClassName("sessioncheckbox")``` note that this selector returns an array of nodeElements but not a single element.

Comment: Are you want to search checkbox inside `<span>` element and get its checked state? If it's true, try using `if ($(this).find('.check-box').prop('checked')) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` function used to get HTML element by its `id` attribute, but you're using CSS selector which will return null value because the element's `id` attribute with specified selector is not found.

Assumed that the checkbox exists inside `<span>` element, you should use [`jQuery.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and `this` selector to find checkbox state instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sessioncheckbox").each(function () {
        // check checked state of checkboxes
        if ($(this).find(".check-box").prop("checked")) {
            $(".sessioncheckbox").addClass("badge badge-default trigger");
        };
    });
});
```

For vanilla JS, use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (or `document.querySelectorAll()` depending on number of elements) with `checked` to extract checkbox state:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sessioncheckbox").each(function () {
        // check checked state of checkboxes
        if (document.querySelector(".sessioncheckbox").querySelector(".check-box").checked) {
            $(".sessioncheckbox").addClass("badge badge-default trigger");
        };
    });
});
```

**Note:**

1) `:checkbox` selector can also be used if the checkbox doesn't have specific class name.

2) Disabled input elements will not posted on server-side. To prevent user input but still allowing postback to server, use `readonly="readonly"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for that but its formatting all checkboxes now, not just the ones that are ticked :-) For both :checkbox and ".check-box".